# How to remove divider in lastmost List item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

This is my code where I attempt to use NavigationLinks as some sort of menu:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    Text("Link A")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    Text("Link B")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    Text("Link C")
                }
                Text("Footer content here")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Is there a way I can remove the `Divider` that appears on the bottom-most item, i.e. the line just below where it says "Footer content here"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
extension View {
    func listRowUpperSeparator() -> some View {
        self.listRowBackground(
            VStack {
                Divider().padding(.leading)
                Spacer()
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    Text("Link A")
                }.listRowUpperSeparator()
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    Text("Link B")
                }.listRowUpperSeparator()
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test")) {
                    Text("Link C")
                }.listRowUpperSeparator()
                Text("Footer content here")
                    .listRowUpperSeparator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```